# Javascript array handling, differences between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cross-browser

I'm experiencing an issue where Firefox and Chrome behave differently when interpreting an array.
The array is generated from a select element which can have multiple options.

```js
var asset = {};

var fCategories = []; //List of category values
$('#selectCategory option:selected').each(function() {
  fCategories.push($(this).val());
});
if (fCategories.length === 1 && fCategories[0] != "null") {
  asset.Asset_Category_id = fCategories[0];
}
if (fCategories.length > 1) {
  asset.category_list = fCategories.join(",");
}


console.log(asset);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectCategory" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="null">Filter Category</option>
  <option selected value="3">Arc Welder</option>
  <option selected value="4">Bench Grinder.</option>
  <option value="41">cables</option>
</select>
```

The resulting Asset category id or category list are used as parameters in a call to a web service.
Results below are for single option selected and for two options selected.

Firefox gives:
`details: {"Asset_Category_id":"4"}` or `details: {"category_list":"3,4"}`

Chrome gives:
`details: {"Asset_Category_id":["3"]}` or `details: {"Asset_Category_id":["3","4"]}`

Which isn't right.

Browser versions are
Firefox 70.0.1 (64-bit)
Chrome Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I had hoped to spot a problem with the code as I typed this, but no luck, so I would really appreciate the input of the Stackoverflow community.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Chrome and Firefox give identical results: http://snpy.in/ME9nMm

Comment: My bad. I hadn't realised that chrome is very reluctant to reload javascripts, favouring using the out of date versions in cache. Became clear when I added the console.log statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this. The issue was Chrome caching an out of date version of the javascript code.
Not being a regular Chrome user, I was unaware that f5 refresh doesn't also reload code.